# Why can I only vote to migrate to Meta, instead of another S-E Site?

Tags: discussion, flagging, migration

I recently flagged a post for moderator attention, as it had a couple of problems with it:

- The post did not have a practical, answerable question
- The post was more appropriate for The WorkPlace than Personal Finance & Money

[This](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/81099/help-understanding-my-bonus-offer) is the question I'm referring to.

I wanted to flag it to close or flag it to migrate, but when attempting to flag it for migration, I didn't have an option to flag for migration to The WorkPlace.

[image: This is what's visible when I attempt to migrate.]

My question is: **What determines which sites a member of the community can flag for migration to?**

Side-question - In cases like this, was it innapropriate for me to flag for moderator attention? What would have been a better avenue for bringing attention to this? Posting a question (like this) in Meta, or chat?

Comment: The whole concept behind migration has a lot of problems, and Stack Exchange [is rethinking how it should be handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285467/232449).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The list of migration targets is configured by StackExchange staff, who would probably take advice from the elected site moderators and perhaps look for consensus on meta. Note that moderators can always migrate something anywhere, and people fairly often raise custom flags asking us to do so.

If we were going to add an extra migration path, Law would be the first choice - it gets the overwhelming majority of migration requests. But TBH I'm not keen. Something should only be migrated if it's both off-topic here and a good question, and in my experience that's pretty rare.

Personally I'd suggest focusing first on closing a question on this site if you think it doesn't fit - i.e. flag/vote to close. If you also really think that it would be a *good* question on another site, raise the custom flag as well. But don't do it just because you think another site is a better fit for the question. In this case according to your own assessment, just flagging to close would have been appropriate.