# Add "vote to move to another site" under "vote to close" options

Tags: feature-request, migration

If a question is off topic because it belongs on another stackexchange, I think it should be easy to vote to migrate it and I can't see how we would do it now except in a comment to a moderator.

In particular, we have many questions come up that should really be in economics.stackexchange.com. According to

[How do I move a question to another Stack Exchange site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169770/how-do-i-move-a-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site)

there should be a migration path that perhaps can be an option when we vote to close the question.  Is this something that can be easily set up?  At present they get put on hold, presumably until a mod moves them.  Not efficient.

I apologize if there's currently an obvious option to do this and I am not seeing it.  I'm basing my belief partly on the frequency with which I find posts on hold because they belong elsewhere.

Comment: Related: [Why can I only vote to migrate to Meta, instead of another S-E Site?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2467/10997)

Comment: On a normal question, if asked directly on site, it can be closed [via votes]; and if edited, can be reopened [via votes]. If a question is migrated to other site, and the new site votes to close, it goes in limbo. So the new site is in dilemma, should they wait eternally for the question to get corrected, or close it and it goes into limbo. Hence the preferred option is if its a new question, ask OP to copy paste it in new site.

Answer (score 5):

Migration seems like an attractive option for a question that is out of place here, but most actual experience is more negative:

- Posters sometimes don't follow their migrated question so it becomes a bit academic.
- If the poster didn't put some effort into choosing a good site, they often also didn't put effort into writing a good question.
- Questions in need of migration tend to be subjective and it takes some effort to judge whether it'll be on-topic on the target site.

Summarising [general SE guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work), a question should only be migrated if it's

1. A good question in general
2. On-topic on the target site
3. One of

   - Already closed as off-topic on the original site or obviously off-topic
   - The poster requests migration

Conditions 1 and 2 actually rule out quite a lot of questions. Overall we have maybe 1-2 migrations a month in each direction, which doesn't [meet the thresholds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261196/when-should-we-consider-adding-a-default-migration-path) for adding a "standard" migration path that users can use.

Comment: Thanks, Ganesh.  This makes sense.  To be clear, though, am I to understand that there are 1-2 questions per month for which the poster requests migration?  Perhaps this could be taken as evidence that the current process is too hard (for the users and for us), rather than that there are few questions worthy of migration.  I am certain I see more than 1-2 questions per month that I think are worthy of migration (and would be willing to answer if they were on economics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There are 1-2 questions that are actually migrated.  I don't easily have stats on how many are suggested, but as per my answer I tend to be fairly careful about accepting. Anyone can use a moderator flag to suggest migration, though we'd be more likely to give it the benefit of the doubt if the OP requested it (either by flagging or in the comments).